# .ipynb file not opening on anaconda. Python 3.9 and jupyter are installed

Tags: python

.ipynb file not opening on anaconda. Python 3.9 and jupyter installed. This is what I get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMpSP.png)

Comment: Are you using the Anaconda navigator to open Jupyter and then open your file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.